# Recursive Destructors and Types

Tags: c++, recursion, memory-management, tree, destructor

I am programming a search tree that will consist of two types: MatrixNode and ChanceNode.
Both MatrixNode and ChanceNode have the following three members: parent, next, and child.

However, the structure of the tree is such that the two types of node will alternate. The child of a MatrixNode is a ChanceNode and so on. "Next" is always the same type.

I am trying to define a Destructor for these classes. I want to do a recursive destructor at this point since I don't believe the recursion will cause a stack overflow, and I am not knowing just yet how to do it via other means.

When defining these classes I had to use a foward declaration for ChanceNode due to the 'cyclic' nature of the types. I tried something similar with the destructors:

```
class ChanceNode;

class MatrixNode {
public:
    ChanceNode* parent = nullptr;
    ChanceNode* child = nullptr;
    MatrixNode* next = nullptr;

    ~MatrixNode ();
};

class ChanceNode {
public:
    MatrixNode* parent = nullptr;
    MatrixNode* child = nullptr;
    ChanceNode* next = nullptr;

    ~ChanceNode () {
        delete child;
        delete next;
    };
};

MatrixNode :: ~MatrixNode() {
    delete child;
    delete next;
}
```

However this does not work:

```
build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/surskit.dir/src/main.cc.o: in function `State::actions(PairActions)':
[build] /home/user/Desktop/surskit/src/tree/node.hh:59: multiple definition of `MatrixNode::~MatrixNode()'; CMakeFiles/surskit.dir/src/tree/node.cc.o:/home/user/Desktop/surskit/src/tree/node.hh:59: first defined here
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/surskit.dir/src/main.cc.o: in function `State::actions(PairActions)':
[build] /home/user/Desktop/surskit/src/tree/node.hh:59: multiple definition of `MatrixNode::~MatrixNode()'; CMakeFiles/surskit.dir/src/tree/node.cc.o:/home/user/Desktop/surskit/src/tree/node.hh:59: first defined here
```

Is it possible to have a recursive destructor in this case? By the way, I tried declaring a base Node class and deriving Matrix and Chance node from this. This way, I could define the recursive destructor in the base class. But this seems even less viable.

Comment: Try putting the destructor for the `MatrixNode` class in a cpp file and compile/link with that.

Comment: Functions definitions (as opposed to declarations) should either be hidden in .cpp files, **or** be `inline`.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a class method (including constructors and destructors) outside the class then the will be defined every time the header is included leading to multiple definitions.

There are 2 solutions to this:

1. Put the method in a cpp file so it only gets compiled once.
2. Mark the method as `inline` so all versions of the method collapse into a single instance when linking.